# Upperbound eigenvalues of real square matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a real square matrix A (potentially even containing negative numbers) and given λ as an existing real eigenvalue of A.

Is the following upperbound correct?

$$| \lambda | \leqslant \max_i (\sum_{j=1}^n | A_{ij} |)$$

This is the reasoning:

$$ Av = \lambda v \tag{1} $$
$$ \lambda v = w \tag{2} $$
$$ w_i = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}v_j \tag{3} $$
$$ w_i \leqslant ( \sum_{j=1}^n |A_{ij} | ) \cdot \max_j | v_j | \tag{4} $$
$$ \max_i | w_i | \leqslant \max_i (\sum_{j=1}^n | A_{ij} |) \cdot \max_i | v_i | \tag{5} $$
$$ | \lambda | \cdot \max_i | v_i | \leqslant \max_i (\sum_{j=1}^n | A_{ij} |) \cdot \max_i | v_i | \tag{6} $$
$$ | \lambda | \leqslant \max_i (\sum_{j=1}^n | A_{ij} |) \tag{7} $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\max_i \sum_{j=1}^n | A_{ij} |$ is the induced $l_\infty$ norm.

For **any** norm and **any** eigenvalue, if $Ax = \lambda x$ (with $u$ being a unit vector) then taking the norm of both sides gives $\|Ax\| = |\lambda|$ and since
$\|Ax\| \le \|A\|$ we have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a consequence of the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)

Comment: That is a bit of a sledgehammer.

Comment: Only because of the name of the theorem I guess, because the proof is very simple.